# I would like to rewrite this URL (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite this url in APACHE with RewriteRule

```
http://localhost/info.php?id=1000
```

to

```
http://localhost/folder/1000.html
```

I spent hours to solve this problem but it didn't work.

Without the `/folder/` in the pattern it works but adding `folder` it does not.

This solution works:

```
 RewriteEngine
    on RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.html$ info.php?id=$1
```

but this does not work:

```
 RewriteRule ^/folder/([\w-]+)\.html$ info.php?id=$1
```

What is missing

Comment: Does the url /folder/1000.html exist?

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. I'd say: go for it! Report back when you did it!

Comment: Please note that SO is _not_ a free coding service. We are _not_ here to do your work for you. We are here to help with _specific issues_ you encounter _in your own code_. So start out yourself, if you run into serious issues, _then_ is the time to come here, post your code and point out that issue you ran into.

Comment: the url http://localhost/folder/1000.html not exist

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution by removing the first slash  /

```
 RewriteRule ^folder/([\w-]+)\.html$ info.php?id=$1
```